# Chrome is showing black screen with tabs named untitled?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

[image]Suddenly Chrome is showing a black screen with tabs named Untitled. Even the settings page won't work. Here is the image of what's happening. I tried reinstalling but it's the same.

Answer (score 6):

Try killing all the Chrome processes in Task Manager, and then re-open without restoring tabs from the old session. Rebooting your computer would achieve the same thing if that's easier.

If that doesn't work, disable all your Chrome Extensions (if you have any), and if that works, enable them back one-by-one to find the problematic one.

If that doesn't work, follow the instructions to [Reset Chrome settings to default](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en-GB), as it's possible some setting got changed unintentionally.

If that doesn't work, the simplest solution would be to reinstall Chrome, presumably at this point something in the file system got corrupted.

Comment: I tried reinstalling but it didn't work. It's showing the same thing

Comment: @ashwinmurthy When you uninstall, make sure you delete the `AppData\Local\Google` directory completely and reboot before installing again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

**Okey this did worked for me!!!**

My problem was like yours.I immediately pressed Ctrl+Alt+Del aka Task Manager and switched over to the **Details** TAB therein
I scrolled down to the Chrome.exe  and selected it to "End Task" and as I ended up the chrome and restarted it it worked flawlessly...
Hope this works for You